# Mount EFS inside a git repo, what could possibly go wrong?

Tags: git, amazon-efs

I have sizable codebase called `my-amazing-project` tracked by git. One of the subdirectories in this, `my-amazing-project/efs-stuff/`, contains Python scripts that is destined to live on an AWS EFS directory. Instead of manually copying these files from my git repo to the EFS every time I change them, what if I just mount the EFS at `my-amazing-project/efs-stuff/`? From gits perspective, it will be like any other directory, there shouldn't be git stuff in it because that's all in the top-level dir, and IDEs like Pycharm should also keep subdirectories reasonably clean.

Is there some serious problem with this strategy that I am overlooking, or is EFS mount under a git-tracked directory a reasonably safe thing to do?

Answer (score 3):

In general, this is not a good idea.  Git doesn't expect your data to be spread across file systems, and you may end up with unexpected results.

If your EFS isn't mounted, then Git will check out files into the non-EFS directory, which will then disappear when you mount the EFS volume.  In addition, some file systems don't like it when you mount over a non-empty directory, so your EFS volume may fail to mount in that case.

In addition, Git stores the device and inode into the index.  If the device or inode number changes (say, due to a remount), Git will refresh all of those files, thinking they may have been changed.  That can be slow.

Within the EFS volume, you'll also need to set the environment variable `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM`, since Git will by default not traverse mount points when looking for a `.git` directory.

The better way to handle this would be to mount the EFS directory to a different directory and then do a local push from your repository to a repository on the EFS mount (possibly with the latter using `receive.denyCurrentBranch` set to `updateInstead`).  That would mean you'd have to push explicitly, but it would be fast and on the local machine, and you wouldn't have to worry about the problems of working across file systems.